# LIBGDX Input isTouched()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Can anyone give me any tips why my Player isn't moving?  It started moving till the player.dat was saved then it just Kind of nudges and returns to original position

```
public class Player implements Serializable, InputProcessor{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Vector2 position, touchPosition;
String textureLoc;

public Player(Vector2 position, String textureLoc){
    this.position = position;
    }

public void update(){
    
    position = new Vector2(0,0);
    Vector2 touchPosition = new Vector2(0,0);
    
    
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        touchPosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
    
    }
    if(touchPosition.x > position.x){
        position.x += 2f;}
        
     if (touchPosition.x < position.x){
            position.x -= 2f;}
    
    if(touchPosition.y > position.y){
        position.y += 2f;}
        
     if (touchPosition.y < position.y){
            position.y -= 2f; 
    }
    
}
```

This is under `Player` class.

Answer (score 2):

Move this to the constructor:

```
position = new Vector2(0,0);
```

If you have this line in your `update` you reset the `position`every time.

ps: you might also get in trouble with your private and global touchPosition